# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decode') NestJs

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs, decode

**I'm trying to get the information stored in my jwt in Nestjs.But I'm getting the following error**

> [Nest] 16960  - 19/12/2022, 10:22:28 pm   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler]
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decode') TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'decode')
> at AdminGuard.canActivate (D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\MAN STACK\Cybrnode-Blog-Backend\Cybr-Blog-Nest-Backend\src\guard\admin.guard.ts:28:34)
>
> at GuardsConsumer.tryActivate (D:\Noum\Data\CYBRNODE\MAN STACK\Cybrnode-Blog-Backend\Cybr-Blog-Nest-Backend\node_modules@nestjs\core\guards\guards-consumer.js:15:34)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

**code**

```
export type PayloadType = {
      id: string;
    };
```

**code. I can see that token is present through console**

```
  let jwtService: JwtService;

    let token = AuthenticationService.jwtToken.accessToken;
    console.log(token);

    if (token) {
      const payload = jwtService.decode(token.split('')[1]) as PayloadType;
      console.log(payload);

    }
```

Comment: Here `jwtService` is undefined, better `console.log("jwtService", jwtService)` before setting the payload to make sure it is not undefined

Comment: so if jwtService is undefined what I should to do about that?

Comment: console.log this `AuthenticationService`, see why it doesn't have `jwtToken`

Comment: The jwt token should be sent as an Authorization header in your request. The logic to decode and validate it should be part of a guard

Comment: I'm trying to get the info after user login

Comment: The jwt should be sent as an Authorization header in every request.

Comment: I got your point. Btw I'm writing this in my guard

Comment: Then you can get the request using this const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
 and then you should be able to get the authorization header from that

Comment: Look I know about that, The thing is I'm trying to implement a logic which is a user will be able to request something when  the Id stored in jwt(which generated when login) is equal to the id present in request. I hope I was able to explain myself in an understandable way

Comment: I don't want to request any thing. I want to see the information that is stored in jwt when user logs in

Comment: @DanteDX
Now my `jwtService` is not undefine but I'm getting payload as `null`

Comment: I am not sure what you are using to decode the jwt but we use jsonwebtoken. Try the following. `import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';` then you should be able to decode it with the following `var { header, payload, signature } = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });` Then you should be able to log the payload to see what's inside it. The user id should be the subject 'sub' of the payload

Comment: I'm using `JwtService` from `@nestjs/jwt`

Comment: @mh377
Ok with that Import I'm getting the id stored in token. Thanks a lot for your time and  help!

Answer (score 2):

Always make sure the **Imports**

**I was using**

```
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
```

**But according to **@mh377** the following import is used to `decode`**

```
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
```

**Example according to my code**

```
let token = AuthenticationService.jwtToken;

    var { header, payload, signature } = jwt.decode(token.accessToken, {
      complete: true,
    });
    console.log('ID', payload.sub);
```